# Multiple signatures using react-native-signature-capture saved in same file

Tags: react-native, signature

I am working on React-Native app that is collecting multiple signatures using react-native-signature-capture

When I want to upload resulting file to Amazon S3 using result.pathName
I always get the same file as a result. Every new signature is being written to the same file internally, i.e: /Users/adnan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devic…53-4B89-84A2-B2D72D004241/Documents/signature.png

When I use base64 (result.encoded) then it always return different signature, as expected, but I want the file to be uploaded to S3 and therefore I use result.pathName and everything works but I am getting the same signature for all users.

```py
    onSaveEvent = (result) =>        
        {this.props.dispatch(setFieldParticipantAction('current_participant_sign_uri',result.pathName))
        this.setState({ isVisible: false })
    }

    onDragEvent = () => {
        this.setState({sigChanged: true }) 
    }

    saveSign() {
        this.refs["sign"].saveImage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the code from this pull request, and it made my component work with multiple signatures getting unique file names:
https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture/pull/179[Pull request](https://github.com/RepairShopr/react-native-signature-capture/pull/179)